# Function Type which Returns Itself

Tags: c++, c++11, types, self-reference

I'm trying to write a very minimal state machine in C++. I'd like the states to be methods of the machine's class, and each state, when run, should return the new state to move to. Naturally, I'm using a few typedef's to help out.

```
template <typename C, typename E>
using State = State<C, E> (C::*)(Stream<E>&);
```

A state should be a member function (in class `C`) which takes a stream object and yields a new state. I'm getting the following error.

```
fsm.hpp:8:15: error: ‘State’ does not name a type
 using State = State<C, E> (C::*)(Stream<E>&);
```

Obviously, `State` is not declared yet on the line that should declare `State`. As far as I know, there's no way to "forward declare" a typedef, so what is the appropriate way to declare this typename?

Comment: `State` corresponds only to the function (well, method) type. The state machine itself is type `C`, an argument to `State`. I don't need individual class instances for each state; I just need the functions.

Comment: To clarify, I want `State<C, E>` to be a method which takes an argument and then returns a new `State<C, E>`, which itself is a method, not a class instance.

Comment: I see, I guess I misread your code.

Comment: Can you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)? From what little you've posted, it looks like you have a class template named `State` and you're trying to define an alias also named `State`.

Comment: @Praetorian: I thought so too at first but I think that's not actually what's going on, he wants `State<C,E>` to refer to the currently-being-defined alias type.

Comment: @ChrisBeck That dup is just the explanation I was looking for. I'll have to find a way to do it indirectly then.

Comment: @ChrisBeck Ah ok, that makes more sense. Guess the dupe you found answers the question then.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure if I can explain *why* what you tried didn't work -- I don't know if `using` declarations are allowed to be self-referential, maybe they aren't.

But, certainly, in a class template, the name of the class which is currently being defined is injected into the class scope, so you can do it that way.

In this version, I make a class type that is a thin wrapper over a member function pointer. I believe that the optimizer should basically eliminate it this wrapper, but it enables you to do what you want, by taking advantage of injected class name.

This compiles and runs in gcc 5.2.0

```
template <typename T>
struct Stream {};

template <typename C, typename E>
class State {
  typedef State (C::*func_t)(Stream<E>&);

  func_t f_;

public:
  State(func_t _f) : f_(_f) {}

  State operator()(C & c, Stream<E> & s) const {
    return (c.*f_)(s);
  }
};





struct Foo {
  State<Foo, int> state_one(Stream<int> &) { return &Foo::state_two; } 
  State<Foo, int> state_two(Stream<int> &) { return &Foo::state_one; } 
};

int main() {
  Foo f;
  Stream<int> s;
  f.state_one(s);
}
```

Comment: This is more or less what I ended up doing. One of the answers in the duplicate question was similar to this.